# What/Where is the SharePoint App server, where to point the DNS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, farm-solution, farm

I am trying to setup the SharePoint 2013 farm for apps.

We have 2 farms:

Test DB Server
Test Central Admin
Test Front End 1
Test Front End 2

Prod DB Server
Prod Central Admin
Prod Front End 1
Prod Front End 2

and a Content Server that will eventually publish to prod and or test.

I am working on the Content Server. I created the web applications, site collection and solution installed and ready. The App Management Service and Subscription service is running.

Now I need to install my app part so I need to setup my farm for apps...

So out of all these machines what should the app domain be?

I have created an app domin, for example, appsmycorp.com. Where machine on the farm should this "point" to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SharePoint Servers are your "app" servers.

You will create a wildcard CNAME record in your app domain that points back to your SharePoint server DNS record.  Make sure that the the farm that receives it does not have host headers configured on the webapp that the requests will be delivered too.  On production using SSL you will have to extend or create another webapp since you can't bind multiple SSL certificates.

You can utilize the same zone for both production and dev by utilizing sub domains. for example:

prod.appsmycorp.com
(A)*.prod.appsmycorp.com --> Prod farm IP
dev.appsmycorp.com
(A) *.dev.appsmycorp.com --> Dev farm IP

Bear in mind that you need 2 wildcard certificates (if using SSL ), one for each sub-domain, you can't use one for the primary domain (appsmycorp.com) with this scenario.

Tech net has a good starting point (and there are plenty of examples on the net):
http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/01/31/configuring-sharepoint-on-premise-deployments-for-apps.aspx

Comment: There are many machines in my farm(s). Which IP address do I use?

Comment: User facing endpoint - typically the servers that are load balanced, most likely what you are referencing as your "front end".  When you use and "app" you are accessing that URL thru that domain namespace.

Comment: Note I have 2 domains devappsmycorp.com and prodappsmycorp.com. Not SSL yet.

Comment: Ok, so I would use the IP address that was used for load balancing for the Front Ends.

Comment: So, since I am currently only setting up the content server I don't need to do this yet (Set-SPAppDomain $AppDomainName and Set-SPAppSiteSubscriptionName -Name $AppPreFixName)

Comment: Same applies - you set them both up so they point to the correct farms.  I would strongly consider using SSL on your production farm.  It is considered a basic level of security when implementing SharePoint.

Comment: If you want to use apps you have to configure them and complete all steps necessary.

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience. What machines do I run Set-SPAppDomain and Set-SPAppSiteSubscriptionName on. The 2 central admin servers? Content Server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21481/discussion-between-ginalster-and-jesus-shelby).